# How do I add new line in for each loop in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, newline

I want to add new line between the strings from the loop. I want to add new line between the key element and values. I've tried with the below code, but it's not happened.

Expecting result :

```
  Name
  Devan

  Dept
  Apple

  Domain
  iOS
```

code:

```
    let dict = convertToDictionary(text : jsonString)
    if let dictData = dict {
        for index in 0..<contentArray.count
        {
            let data = contentArray[index]
            let (key, value) = getKeyAndValue(contentData : dictData , keyElement : data)
            content += "\r\n \(key) \r\n \(value)"
            textView.attributedText = content.htmlToAttributedString
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you simply add another linebreak (\n) after `value` when you concatenate the string? `content += "\r\n \(key) \r\n \(value)\r\n"`.

Comment: Do like this :
var items = ["Bear":"0", "Glass":"1", "Car":"2"]

for (key,value) in items{

print("\(key) \n \(value)\n\n")

}

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, Have tried already. Nothing happened.

Comment: Strange but I only tested with a string and the `print` command, maybe it has something to do with `htmlToAttributedString`. Perhaps you need to add a tag for it, like <p> or <br> or something so that it is proper html

Comment: @JoakimDanielson. Oh my bad. Good catch. Cos of  html text,  not able to add the new line properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **`reduce(_:_:)`** on the `dictionary` to get the required result.

```
let dict = ["Name":"Devan", "Dept":"Apple", "Domain":"iOS"]
let contentArray = ["Name", "Dept", "Domain"]

var str = contentArray.reduce("") { (result, key) -> String in
    if let value = dict[key] {
        return result + key + "\n" + value + "\n\n"
    }
    return result
}

print(str)
```

Comment: You should know that dictionaries are not ordered so this will/might generate different output each time which is not wanted.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't think ordering is a requirement for this question, that's why OP chose dictionary over array.

Comment: Look carefully at OP's code, it uses an array to get the values from the dictionary in the correct order

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yup. Missed that. Thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: @PGDev your contentArray is static that's why it is working. what happens if keys are unexpected?

Comment: I@JatinPatel  it will work even if the keys are unexpected. Only the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
for index in 0..<contentArray.count{
   let data = contentArray[index]
   let (key, value) = getKeyAndValue(contentData : dictData , keyElement : data)
   content.append("\(key) \n \(value) \n\n")
   textView.attributedText = content.htmlToAttributedString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution:**

```
var dict = ["Name":"Deven","Dept":"Apple","Domain":"iOS"]

for (index, entry) in dict {
    print(index)   // Name       Dept        Domain
    print(entry)
    print("\n")// Deven    Apple    iOS
}
```

Comment: You should know that dictionaries are not ordered so this will/might generate different output each time which is not wanted.

Comment: is the 2nd comment misplaced? should it be on line above? just wondering if it has a meaning I didn't grok)